# Cannot POST A COLUMN RESTFUL API

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have made restful API Using java hibernate jersery Framework.

I have to post data I have done it but I'm missing with one of the column that is `MealTypeName`.
Here is my DAO Class:

```
public class MealTypeDAO {

public void addMealType( MealType bean) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    addMealType(session, bean);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}

private void addMealType(Session session, MealType bean){
    MealType mealType = new MealType();
    mealType.setMealTypename(bean.getMealTypename());
    mealType.setModifiedon(bean.getModifiedon());
    mealType.setModifiedby(bean.getModifiedby());
    session.save(mealType);
}
```

Here is my resource class:

```
public class MealTypeResource {

@POST
@Path("/create")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addMealType(MealType meal){
    meal.setMealTypename(meal.getMealTypename());
    meal.setModifiedon(meal.getModifiedon());
    meal.setModifiedby(meal.getModifiedby());

    MealTypeDAO dao = new MealTypeDAO();
    dao.addMealType(meal);
    return Response.ok().build();
}

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getMealType() {
    MealTypeDAO dao = new MealTypeDAO();
    List mealTypes = dao.getMealType();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(mealTypes);
    return Response.ok().entity(json.toString()).build();
}
```

This is my entity class:

```
public class MealType {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int MealTypeId;
@Column
private String MealTypename;
@Column
private int modifiedby;
@Column
private String modifiedon;


public int getMealTypeId() {
    return MealTypeId;
}

public void setMealTypeId(int mealTypeId) {
    MealTypeId = mealTypeId;
}

public String getMealTypename() {
    return MealTypename;
}

public void setMealTypename(String mealTypename) {
    MealTypename = mealTypename;
}

public int getModifiedby() {
    return modifiedby;
}

public void setModifiedby(int modifiedby) {
    this.modifiedby = modifiedby;
}

public String getModifiedon() {
    return modifiedon;
}

public void setModifiedon(String modifiedon) {
    this.modifiedon = modifiedon;
}
```

MySQL DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `mealtype`(`Mealtypeid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`MealTypename` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,`modifiedby` int(11) NOT NULL,`modifiedon` datetime NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`Mealtypeid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now M posting these data in JSON FORMAT From POSTMAN:

```
{"MealTypeId":14,"MealTypename":"adsdf","modifiedby":1,"modifiedon":"2000-01-01 00:00:00"}
```

And M getting these data:

```
{"MealTypeId":14,"modifiedby":1,"modifiedon":"2000-01-01 00:00:00"}
```

`MealTypename` is missing. How so? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using names with the first letter in the upper case `MealTypename` — this is a reason.

The getter  with name `getMealTypename` is used for a JSON property `mealTypename` (not `MealTypename`):

```
public String getMealTypename() {
    return MealTypename;
}
```

You need to specify a JSON property name:

`@JsonProperty("MealTypename")` — for Jackson

`@SerializedName("MealTypename")` — for Gson

You need to put this annotation to the field or getter of the class which you mapping to JSON (`MealType`).

And use the standard Java naming convention.

```
public class MealType {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int mealTypeId;

@Column
private String mealTypename;

}
```

And this looks really strange:

```
meal.setMealTypename(meal.getMealTypename());
meal.setModifiedon(meal.getModifiedon());
meal.setModifiedby(meal.getModifiedby());
```

Comment: private String mealTypename;
    @Column

Made the Changes But Still Not Working.

Comment: @mree  You need to put `@JsonProperty("MealTypename")` to the getter. An, probably, specify `@Column` name, if you want to use `MealTypename` in the database.

Comment: Where i need to put this @JsonProperty("MealTypename")?? In Entity Class??